# Can I launch Fallout: New Vegas via Fallout 3's launcher on Steam?

Tags: steam, mods, fallout-new-vegas, fallout-3

I have Fallout: New Vegas and Fallout 3 on steam and I want to try TTW mod 
(F3 into new vegas)
That mod is for Fallout: New Vegas and I would like to know if there is any way to start falloutnv.exe via falloutlauncher.exe (F3 launcher)

Comment: What you're suggesting doesn't make sense. The TTW mod changes your Fallout: New Vegas install, it doesn't change Fallout 3. To play the TTW mod you need to start Fallout: New Vegas.

Comment: Theoretically, you can. Just move all gamefiles over and rename the .exe accordingly. But it is kind of futile. The mod is for FNV. So play FNV. I don't see the issue here.

Comment: Technically it's possible but you'd break Fallout 3 in the process for literally no gain.

Comment: @CloseVoters: This may be a 'bad' question, but it isn't 'unclear' what the OP is asking. Please remember to use Close Votes [only for questions that fit the close-vote criteria](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5498/28182)

Comment: @Mike - do you not have a Steam version of New Vegas?

Comment: @Robotnik The two comments at the top seem to be doing a pretty good job of explaining why the Unclear votes are happening.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: @Frank - It isn't *'hard to tell what is being asked'*, nor does it require *'[clarification of the] specific problem or...additional details'*. I could ask how to import the CoD: Modern Warfare storyline into CoD: Modern Warfare, sure it'd be a stupid question deserving to be downvoted to oblivion, but that in an of itself does not make it unclear what I'm asking. :)

Comment: @Robotnik It could be; I don't know enough of the problem space to be sure.  The point I'm making, though, is that some people think it's justified for Unclear votes, and I can kinda see where they're coming from.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the Tales of Two Wastelands (TTW) mod is a mod that brings the **content** of Fallout 3 *into* Fallout: New Vegas. You *have* to start Fallout: New Vegas in order to get it to work.

> #### What is Tale of Two Wastelands (TTW)?
>
> Tale of Two Wastelands (TTW) is a project that seeks to merge the content from the popular video game Fallout 3 into the more modern game engine of Fallout New Vegas so that both games can be played in the Fallout New Vegas engine.
> <sub>- [TTW FAQ](https://taleoftwowastelands.com/content/faq#whatisttw)</sub>

If it was possible to use TTW mod and the Fallout 3 launcher, you would need to install the TTW mod into Fallout 3. Even if we ignore how much stuff would break when TTW loads up and starts looking for New Vegas items and objects, this would also just bring all the *Fallout 3* content into... Fallout 3. **No New Vegas stuff would carry over,** it would be an exercise in futility.

Comment: I'm confused... doesn't New Vegas use the same engine as Fallout 3?

Comment: @Powerlord - similar yes, however New Vegas is more polished and has less bugs. The whole point of the TTW mod is to bring Fallout 3 into NV so it can take advantage of the newer engine, therefore launching it with Fallout 3 makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can conceive of doing this, is an attempt to preserve your F3 FOMM settings (or to use a mod that's not compatible with `NV.esm`, without which TTW won't work anyway). You have to import all that into NV's FOMM/GeMM list.

Here's the important part of my load order for NV, with TTW, using [NVSE](https://www.google.com/search?q=new%20vegas%20script%20extender&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) to launch it:

[image]